# Spring Security - always get roleAnonymous when post using POSTMAN / REST Console

Tags: java, rest, oauth, spring-security

Why do I always get Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS when post request in two legged oauth 1.0 using POSTMAN / REST Console in chrome? but when posting in java using OAuthConsumerSupport by spring-security I can get Granted Authorities: ROLE_CONSUMER.

Header in REST Console:

```
{authorization=[OAuth oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1" oauth_version="1.0" oauth_nonce="sZepp" oauth_timestamp="1388722228" oauth_consumer_key="openweb-consumer-key" oauth_signature="Y0rj3518AuqPVC%2Fb%2F3XEKaTudH4%3D"], accept-encoding=[gzip,deflate,sdch], content-length=[0], connection=[keep-alive], accept-language=[en-US,en;q=0.8], host=[localhost:11831], accept-charset=[ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Iron/25.0.1400.0 Chrome/25.0.1400.0 Safari/537.22], cookie=[JSESSIONID=2bf5703e6836f0a1c1a6ccb6f523], content-type=[application/xml], origin=[chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn], accept=[text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2]}
```

Header in OAuthConsumerSupport:

```
{authorization=[OAuth oauth_consumer_key="openweb-consumer-key", oauth_nonce="24dde02e-a018-4f5c-9f19-a516ebe5b4cf", oauth_signature="x9oskqVVSU4B2LV%2FAlWS6XlHRRc%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1388723102", oauth_version="1.0"], connection=[keep-alive], host=[localhost:11831], user-agent=[Java/1.6.0_18], accept=[text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2]}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right JSESSIONID? This usually changes during authentication.

Comment: send request in incognito mode (header without JSESSIONID) the result is still same. request in browser will get role anonymous. role consumer only recognize if request use java program

Comment: fixed in REST Console by adding separator "," but i can't insert form parameter